# Can't install software-properties-common

Tags: apt

```
Package software-properties-common is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'software-properties-common' has no installation candidate
```

System: Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1219303/19626) above to show us the complete output of `sudo apt-get update`

Answer (score 1):

This package [exists](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/software-properties-common) in xenial repositories, so make sure your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file contains [the next entries](https://gist.github.com/rohitrawat/60a04e6ebe4a9ec1203eac3a11d4afc1) uncommented:

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
```

Then do `sudo apt update` and try again